# Java project with smart card support

Tags: java, command, line, project, javacard

I am trying to build a Java project that uses smart card suppport. For that I am using Java card technology.  I have acr38u-l1 smart card reader and acos3 smart cards.  As suggested by websites, I performed following steps:

1. built the applet.
2. compiled it to create a `class` file.
3. converted it to create `cap` file.
4. generated the scripts.

Now I am required to invoke apdutool using script file from command line. Whenever I do so, it shows:

> apdutool cannot be recognised as an internal or external command

I do not know how to proceed any further.

I am using Eclipse Indigo and Java card toolkit 2.1.2.

If anybody knows how to use smart card support in Netbeans, that would also be helpful.

Comment: to my knowledge acos3 is not a java card

Comment: can u tell any other technology to be used in place of java card?

Comment: The process you described above is exclusive to java cards. there is plenty of cards out there

Answer (score 1):

your *apdutool* is not in the system PATH environment variable.

The Java Card development kit *bin\* directory should be in the PATH .